# React Native - SQLite transaction is not waiting for result

Tags: react-native, sqlite, async-await

I want to fetch data from a database (profile and config etc.) and wait for the data before calling the next functions. I was expectiong, that if I put the transaction in a function, call this function in an async function and wait, this would work, but it doesn't:

```
function getProfileData() {
    return db.transaction(
      tx => {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT value FROM tbl_config WHERE name="user_email"', [], (tx, results) => {
          console.log(results.rows.item(0).value);
          return results.rows.item(0).value;
      });
    }, null, null); 
}

async function fetchData() {
  console.log('before fetch')
  var res = await getProfileData();
  console.log(res);
  console.log('after fetch');
}

fetchData();
```

The console shows me the result from the function *getProfileData()*, but in the async function *var res = await getProfileData()* is undefined.

How do I fetch data step by step?

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
function callback(res){
  console.log(res);
  console.log('after fetch');
}

function getProfileData() {
    return db.transaction(
      tx => {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT value FROM tbl_config WHERE name="user_email"', [], (tx, results) => {
          console.log(results.rows.item(0).value);
          callback(results.rows.item(0).value); <!-- Change here -->
      });
    }, null, null); 
}

async function fetchData() {
  console.log('before fetch')
  await getProfileData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getProfileData`  function is not an async function ...  and you can't do this:

```
await db.transaction(...);
```

The only way to fetch transaction result is through the callback, so you could do something like this:

```
tx => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT value FROM tbl_config WHERE name="user_email"', [], (tx, results) => {
    console.log(results.rows.item(0).value);
    const result = results.rows.item(0).value;
    this.setState({ result  });
});
```

and then you could access `state > result` wherever you want in the code